# Dynamically Selection of items in combobox

Tags: c#-4.0, combobox

i want to add some functionality in combo box. I want that it should behave like Google's Search Box. Like i have added items in combo box from a database Say Name of the Doctors.
i want that as user type name of the doctor or first letter of the name of the doctor, the selection bar goes automatically only to related names.

Any suggestion friends???

Comment: winforms?or asp.net or mvc?

Comment: Winforms @Manish Mishra

Answer (score 0):

try `AutoCompleteMode` of combobox, something like this:

```
сomboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
сomboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
comboBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyStringData();
```

where myStringData is :

```
public AutoCompleteStringCollection MyStringData()
{
    var collection= new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    //you can add names of the doctors retrieved from the database here
    collection.Add("one");
    collection.Add("two");
    collection.Add("three");
    collection.Add("four");

    return collection;
}
```

this would suggest those items which begins with those you typed.

If you want to show selection (highlighting) as you type, you can be a little more creative and create a simple combination of a textbox and gridView, which gets bound everytime `TextChanged` happens on the textBox